# Python Discord Bot - Keep real time message parser from blocking async

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, discord.py

I am writing a Discord Bot to take messages from a live chat and relay them to Discord channel, but want it to have other responsive features. Currently the script relays messages by entering a `while loop` which runs until the right message is recieved.

```py
def chat_parser():
    resp = sock.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
    #print(' - ', end='')
    filtered_response = filter_fighter_announce(resp)

    if resp.startswith('PING'):
        # sock.send("PONG :tmi.twitch.tv\n".encode('utf-8'))
        print("Ponging iirc server")
        sock.send("PONG\n".encode('utf-8'))
        return ''

    elif (len(filtered_response) > 0):
        if (filtered_response.count('ets are OPEN for') > 0):
            filtered_response = get_fighters(filtered_response)
            return filtered_response

    return ''

fight = fight_tracker('')  #initialize first fight object

def message_loop():
    global first_loop_global

    while True:    
        chat_reception = chat_parser()
        if (chat_reception == ''):
            continue
        fight.set_variables(chat_reception)
        return fight.announcement

    return  ''
```

The issue with this is that responsive functions for Discord are stuck waiting for this loop to finish. Here is the other code for reference.

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():

    print('Finding channel...')
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    channel = guild.get_channel(salty_bet_chat_id)
    print('Connected to Channel.')

    try:
        print('Beginning main loop.')
        while True:
            message_out = await message_loop()
            if (message_out != None and message_out != None):

                print('Sending to Discord: ', message_out)
                msg = await channel.send(message_out)
                await msg.add_reaction(fight.fighter_1[1])
                await msg.add_reaction(fight.fighter_2[1])
                print('message sent...')

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('KeyboardInterrupt')
        sock.close()
        exit()

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(reaction):
    print(reaction)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.author)
    print(client.user)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I have tried making async functions out of `chat_parser()` and `message_loo()` and awaiting their return where they are called, but the code is still blocking for the loop. I am new to both async and coding with Discord's library, so I am not sure how to make an async loop function when the only way to start the Discord client is by `client.run(TOKEN)`, which I could not figure out how to incorporate into another event loop.

Comment: Add `await asyncio.sleep(60)` in while loop

Comment: Same issue when adding that to the while loop in `on_ready()`.

Comment: Your function message_loop in your first listing is not an async function.  Therefore it will not multitask with any other task in the same thread, period.  Once it is called it blocks the thread, and therefore blocks the event loop, until it returns.  A solution might be to await on an asyncio.sleep(x) inside the while True: block, and turn the function into an async def function.  Then you will have to change your program to schedule this as a coroutine.  It will have the drawback of slowing the response of the program by up to x (floating point) seconds, but perhaps that's not important.

Comment: @PaulCornelius That did the trick! Changing `message_loop()` to async and awating its return in `on_ready()` as well as adding `asyncio.sleep(60)` to the end of the `while true` in `on_ready` did the trick. I'd be happy to accept your answer if you typed it up.

Comment: If your async code is written correctly, the sleep shouldn't be necessary. You didn't show how the socket is created, but you should use [`asyncio.open_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.open_connection) which will give you a steam with async reading/writing methods.